# Marshal structure to pointer - Byte is OK, Byte() is Not OK

Tags: vb.net, pointers, structure, marshalling, unmanaged

I am trying to get a pointer from a Structure, to pass it over to an unmanaged DLL.

The weird thing is the following, if I use this Structure:

```vb
Structure message
    Public x As Byte
End Structure
```

And build the pointer like this:

```vb
Dim mess As message = New message With {.X = &H33}
Dim sizeOfHeader As Integer = 1

Dim pHeader As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeOfHeader)

Marshal.StructureToPtr(mess, pHeader, True)
```

Everything is fine - I can pass the pointer to my unmanaged application, and get the right information.

However, if I use this Structure (with a Byte array - because I need more than one Byte - with variable length in the future):

```vb
Structure message
    Public x As Byte()
End Structure
```

And build the pointer like this:

```vb
Dim mess As message = New message With {.X = New Byte() {&H33}}
Dim sizeOfHeader As Integer = 1

Dim pHeader As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeOfHeader)

Marshal.StructureToPtr(mess, pHeader, True)
```

It fails - the data received by the unmanaged application is random (not 0x33)

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Sometimes I also get a

> System.AccessViolationException: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

from `Marshal.StructureToPtr` function.

And additionally, sometimes the debugger just ends with code 0xc0000374 (seems to be `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`), but no other info.

Comment: My guess would be that you have to apply the `MarshalAsAttribute` to that field.

Comment: Why do you have `sizeOfHeader` set to `1` there? Use `Marshal.SizeOf` to determine the size of the struct (for sure it's not `1` when the field represents an array). Then, it depends on what the other side is expecting. If you need a fixed size array, marshal the array as `ByValArray`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the replies.
The size doesn't matter, it was just set to 1 for test purposes. I will try to use the MarshalAsAttribute field, and let you know

Comment: I'm going to guess, `Byte` is a Value type but `Byte()` is a Reference type. So, when you use `Byte()`, you're marshalling a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @Manuel The size matters very much as you are allocating 1 byte of memory and then writing way more bytes in there. Why are you trying to get a pointer manually to begin with? It is not required to "pass it over to an unmanaged DLL".

Comment: Hi,
it seems that the following struct definiton corrected the problem:
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Structure message
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=1)>
    Public x() As Byte
End Structure

Answer (score -1):

I think when you use `Byte()`, what you really want is:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(mess.x(0), pHeader, True)
```

You want the address of the first byte in the Structure.